# FBSDKMessengerSharer share a sticker not working in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am trying to share sticker image to fb messenger. But it keep adding white background colour on the image.Here is my code.

```
   FBSDKMessengerShareOptions *options = [[FBSDKMessengerShareOptions alloc] init];
    options.renderAsSticker = YES;
    [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:shareImage withOptions:options];
```

Please help me to fix the issue, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the image in question is not an RGBA image, check that the image going out is at least 32 bit and has an alpha channel.